# Are equinumerous size preserving models of a theory isomorphic?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

If by a size preserving model we mean any bijection between any two elements of it is an element of it. Then:

> is it a thoerem of $\sf ZFC$ that for any theory $T$ any two equinumerous size preserving models of $T$ are isomorphic? That is, there is a bijection between the domains of those models that preserves the relational sets in those models.

Comment: The question makes no sense. There is a countable set of finite sets and a countable set of uncountable sets. Both can model $\Bbb Q$ with its, say, order.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't see the problem? What forbids those being isomorphic, unless you think ismorphism is on membership? By isomorphism here its meant the existence of a bijection between the domains of those models that preserves the relational sets (say here of the order on $\mathbb Q$) of those models.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your definition: $M$ is size preserving model if for each $a≠b∈M$ and $f:a\to b$ bijection in the universe, then $f∈M$? In this case take $M_0,M_1$ be 2 equinumerous non-isomorphic models of $T$ such that for each $a,b\in M_i$ we have $|a|≠|b|$, then both models are trivially equinumerous size preserving models that are not isomorphic

Comment: @Holo, what is your definition of isomorphism?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar isomorphic as models "bijection between the domains of those models that preserves the relational sets"

Comment: If the definition above is correct, any model is isomorphic (as a model) to a size preserving model

Comment: There is no version of this question I can think of which has an affirmative answer. For every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $H_\kappa\models\mathsf{KP}$ (the latter is $T$), and $H_\kappa$ "computes bijectability correctly" (if $A,B\in H_\kappa$ and $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$ then $H_\kappa\models \vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$, since a bijection between sets of size $<\kappa$ is itself an object of size $<\kappa$). But of course $H_{\omega_1}\not\cong H_{\omega_2}$. (And there there are $\kappa<\lambda$ such that $H_\kappa\equiv H_\lambda$, so this can't be fixed by requiring $T$ to be complete.)

Comment: @Holo, can you prove your last statement, why should any model is (model isomorphic) to a size preserving model?

Comment: @NoahSchweber but $H_{\omega_1} ; H_{\omega_2}$ are not equinumerous!

Comment: If I understand your definition correctly, the question of whether a model $M$ is size-preserving depends only on the underlying set of $M$ and not on the interpretation of the symbols in the language. Is that right? If so, the answer to your question is obviously no. If not, you need to provide a clearer definition of "size preserving model".

Comment: E.g. what does it mean to be a size-preserving model of the theory of linear orders? How does the linear order get involved in the definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no version of this question I can think of which has an affirmative answer. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be distinct countable ordinals such that $L_\alpha\equiv L_\beta\equiv L_{\omega_1^L}$ (which exist by downward Lowenheim-Skolem + condensation). Then $L_\alpha\not\cong L_\beta$ (since distinct levels of $L$ are non-isomorphic), $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ are equinumerous (each is countable), and since $L_{\omega_1^L}$ is locally countable (= it sees that each of its infinite elements is in bijection with $\omega$) both $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ are locally countable as well and so a fortiori satisfy your size preserving condition. Now take $T=Th(L_{\omega_1^L})=Th(L_\alpha)=Th(L_\beta)$ (and note that this even gives a counterexample where $T$ is **complete**).

Comment: But I've already mentioned in comments that $H_{\omega_1}$ is not equinumerous to $H_{\omega_2}$, so this, as far as I can see, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I misunderstood your question: I thought "equinumerous" was part of the term you were defining. As it happens, though, they **are** consistently equinumerous, and you asked what $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove, so ...

Comment: The problem with this answer is that $\sf ZFC$ doesn't prove those to be equinumerous, even though its consistent with that, so in reality this is not a typical answer. You need to have the two models to be provably equinumerous in ZFC.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar That's incorrect. You asked "is it a thoerem of  that for any theory  any two equinumerous size preserving models of  are isomorphic?" Since it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $H_{\omega_1}$ and $H_{\omega_2}$ are equinumerous, your statement can't possibly be a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: But we can in fact do better: both $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ and $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}$ are countable models of $\mathsf{KP}$, and each is additionally "locally countable" - that is, each sees that all of its infinite sets are in bijection with $\omega$ - which gives us the condition you're interested in. And we can even extend this to complete $T$: take distinct $\alpha,\beta$ such that $L_\alpha\equiv L_\beta\equiv L_{\omega_1^L}$ (which exist via downward Lowenheim-Skolem and condensation).